# I am getting weird output, when converting void* to char*

Tags: c, pointers, char, printf, void

Those are my flags of compiler:

clang -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic

```
int main(void) {
        unsigned int arr = 23;
        void *ptr = &arr;
        printf("%u\n", (unsigned int)ptr);
        printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)ptr);
        printf("%p\n",ptr);

        char *s = ptr;

        printf("\n%s\n", s);
}
```

I can't understand, how can i assign void* ptr to char *s. In that way i wanna be it in output like:

```
1822581628
140730721002364
0x7ffe6ca2637c

0x7ffe6ca2637c
```

But i am keep getting weird symbol like this

```
1822581628
140730721002364
0x7ffe6ca2637c

 // <-- there is a weird symbol
```

Comment: I'm a little confused at what exactly you want. To get the output you desire you need to simply print out the memory location of `s` by doing `printf("\n%p\n", s);` since `s` is equal to `ptr`. Unless you want the `s` value to hold the `ptr` location as a string, that's a different story.

Answer (score 0):

The format `%s` prints the string the pointer is supposedly pointing to, not the pointer value itself.

The weird symbol is whatever the representation of the integer value translates to if it is seen as a string. Most likely there is a null byte somewhere, so you are just lucky that it doesn't explode under you.

So the title of your question would better be

> I am getting weird output when interpreting an integer as a string.